# FFmpeg - How to achieve a circular video overlay..?

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I'm helping my daughter and her friends with their Youtube VLOG channel, and now they want to do screen-casts and put a smaller circular face close-up (e.g. in a the upper right or left corner) where you can see them talk about the actual thing they're screencasting. I've used FFmpeg for more basic stuff for almost ten years, but I can tell this is more of a complex task.

I stumbled onto another question thread ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42518592/circular-movie-overlay-in-ffmpeg ) thanks to Google, and I think he's trying to accomplish more or less the same, apart from him using the same source for both the small circular overlay and the "main" video, whereas I want to use separate inputs; use "main.mkv" and "facecloseup.mkv" for example command line if anyone is up for solving this delicate task! ;)

For simplicity I'll probably have the two sources with optimized resolution already, say 1080p for the main.mkv and 240x240 or something like that for the facecloseup.mkv and then I just need the math syntax to get a center-circle cropped from facecloseup.mkv and put in some corner, take the upper left for simplicity.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i main.mkv -i facecloseup.mkv
 -filter_complex "[1]trim=end_frame=1,
  geq='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),pow(min(W/2,H/2),2)),255,0)':128:128,
  loop=-1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[mask];
  [1][mask]alphamerge[cutout];
  [0][cutout]overlay=x=W-w:y=0[v];
  [0][1]amix=2[a]"
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]"  out.mp4
```

The commentary video is used to construct a circular grayscale mask centered at the centre of the video. It is then merged as a alpha channel with the source. It is overlaid in the upper-right corner. The audios are mixed together. Remove this last filter and `-map "[a]"` if the main video has no audio.

Comment: Wow, big thanks for a quick response! This was exactly what I was looking for. I would probably never have figured this one out by myself, since my math skills are on a basic arithmetic level, at most. Also, I'm convinced that this post will help others too; I searched the web for almost two hours for existing Q/A but to no avail. The link I posted was the closest I got to finding an answer. Oh, a small add-on question, say I wanted the "bubble" in the upper left corner instead, would that be much hassle achieving? Again, big thanks! This will help me a lot with automation.

Comment: In the overlay filter, the values for `x` and `y` represent where the top-left corner of the overlaid video (cutout) is located with respect to the top-left corner of the base image (main). Here, x is `W-w` i.e. at `full width of main - full width of cutout` which will right-align the two inputs horizontally. Change that to 0 to left-align.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to make sense of the geq filter.
It's not very well documents and I'm not sure what those 3 values that is being used (2 of them are fixed with 128) represent.

Can you please share some details on it or re-direct to a decent documentation of this filter? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To people seeing this in the future, you need to add `-filter_complex_threads 1` at the end for this to work due to a multi-threading bug.

This code worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mkv -i facecloseup.mkv
 -filter_complex "[1]geq='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y- 
  (H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),pow(min(W/2,H/2),2)),255,0)':128:128,
  setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[mask];
  [1][mask]alphamerge[cutout];
  [0][cutout]overlay=x=W-w:y=0[v];
  [0][1]amix=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"  out.mp4 -filter_complex_threads 1
```

I have found that we can simply remove the loop=-1:1 and trim parts as it seems to not affect the final result. In fact, the loop filter resulted in the command generating the video forever on ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0 ubuntu.

Comment: What's the bug?

Comment: @Gyan honestly I have no idea, I read about it on some different question on StackOverflow, but have since lost track of it. Now that I have removed the option it still seems to be working, but I no longer have loop or trim either.